# In simplex method should right hand sides be positive or non-negative?

Tags: linear-programming, simplex-method

let's say we have an optimal basic feasible solution for an LP problem solved by simplex method. In this solution, should the RHSs (right hand side) be positive or non-negative?

Because I read that if a RHS is zero (which means a basic variable takes on the value zero) then there is degeneracy. Thus the zero causes degeneracy on the RHS. But in the definition of Simplex Method it says that RHSs sohuld be non-negative. So which one? I am confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot choose to avoid degeneracy. Degeneracy is not caused by a particular assignment of the variables. It is part of the given problem (e.g. linear dependency of the given constraints, vertices that are determined by more equations than necessary, linear dependency between constraints and objective function etc.) If you have an optimal basic feasible solution with active variables that take the value zero, this assignment of variables *indicates* that there is degeneracy, it does not *cause* it. There is nothing wrong with active variables taking the value zero. (You might have to introduce special handling for those, if you actually *implement* the simplex method.)

Comment: Oh alright. So there can be degeneracy and it still can be an optimal feasible solution, right?

Comment: Right. $\phantom{placeholder}$